# Two arrays (one indicating an index, the other number of repetition) . I want to remove index based on the number of repetition (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working in a colab with some dataframes and I have two numpy arrays:

-First one indicates the index of a row.
-The other one indicates the number of repetitions (I did some methods before all this).

If I print both arrays I get something like this:

```
print(uniqueValues, occurCount)

OUTPUT: [   13    33    66 ... 99907 99911 99928] [7 1 6 ... 1 6 4]
```

We can interpret it as: 13 is repeated 7 times, 33 is repeated 1 time....

Now the question:
How can i remove the index and the repetition from both arrays, based on the number of repetition?

Example:
if < 5 then remove element
Expected output:[   13    66 ... 99911] [7 6 ... 6]

Comment: Can you show your input for uniqueValues and occurCount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the matching values from `occurCount` as a filter on `uniqueValues` and `occurCount` using [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
uniqueValues = uniqueValues[occurCount >= 5]
occurCount = occurCount[occurCount >= 5]
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np

uniqueValues = np.array([13, 33, 66, 99907, 99911, 99928])
occurCount = np.array([7, 1, 6, 1, 6, 4])

uniqueValues = uniqueValues[occurCount >= 5]
occurCount = occurCount[occurCount >= 5]
print(uniqueValues )
print(occurCount)
```

Output:

```
[   13    66 99911]
[7 6 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uniqueValues = np.array([13, 33, 66, 99907, 99911, 99928])
occurCount = np.array([7, 1, 6, 1, 6, 4])

np.array([uniqueValues, occurCount])[:, occurCount >= 5]
```

will return a 2 dim array with your results. but the logic is the same as pointed by Nick.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array where you will append the indexes for occurCount values that meet the criteria of <5. Then use these index value to delete these values from both arrays and store the new version of the array. Need to assign it to the variables because the original np arrays are immutable.

```
import numpy as np

uniqueValues = np.array([13, 33, 66, 99907, 99911, 99928])
occurCount = np.array([7, 1, 6, 1, 6, 4])
indexes = []

for index, item in enumerate(y):
    if item < 5:
        indexes.append(index)
        
y = np.delete(y, indexes)
x = np.delete(x, indexes)
print(x, y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.